# Tables with columns representing row values

Tags: python, sql, r, shell

What is the best way to create a table with column values of 1s and 0s.

```
id,string
1,"x,y,z"
2,"x,z"
3,"x"
```

I need a table which looks like

```
id,x,y,z,a,b,c
1,1,1,1,0,0,0
2,1,0,1,0,0,0
3,1,0,0,0,0,0
```

Also, the full list of all possible unique values in string is predefined.
I have a csv with a list that looks like

```
col
x
y
z
a
b
c
.
.
.
```

Comment: It would help us if you could add your code. In other words, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option using `table` and `melt` in `R`.  We split the 'string' column by `,` into a `list`, set the names of the `list` elements as 'id', `melt` the `list` to a `data.frame`, change the 'value' column to `factor` and include the 'a', 'b', 'c', levels, get the `table` and `cbind` with the `id' column.

```
library(reshape2)
tbl <-  table(transform(melt(setNames(strsplit(df1$string, 
          ','),df1$id)),
        value=factor(value, levels=c(levels(value), letters[1:3])))[2:1])
cbind(df1['id'], as.data.frame.matrix(tbl))
#  id x y z a b c
#1  1 1 1 1 0 0 0
#2  2 1 0 1 0 0 0
#3  3 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

In SQL, you can use `case`:

```
select id,
       (case when string like '%x%' then 1 else 0 end) as x,
       (case when string like '%y%' then 1 else 0 end) as y,
       . . .
from t;
```

There may be simpler formulations, depending on the database.  In addition, this assumes that the values do not overlap -- as they are in your question.  "apple" and "pineapple" would cause a problem, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string and then use `%in%` to match the split values with those in your predefined list of possible values.

Example:

```
mydf <- read.csv(text = 'id,string\n1,"x,y,z"\n2,"x,z"\n3,"x"')

matches <- c("x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c")

cbind(mydf[1], 
      `colnames<-`(t(vapply(strsplit(as.character(mydf$string), ",", TRUE), 
                            function(x) {
                              matches %in% x
                            }, 
                            numeric(length(matches)))), 
                   matches))
#   id x y z a b c
# 1  1 1 1 1 0 0 0
# 2  2 1 0 1 0 0 0
# 3  3 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reshaping.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(tidyr)

'id,string
1,"x,y,z"
2,"x,z"
3,"x"' %>% 
  read.csv(text = .) %>%
  mutate(string_split = 
           string %>% 
           stri_split_fixed(",") ) %>%
  unnest(string_split) %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  spread(string_split, value, fill = 0)
```

Comment: You'll probably need to add a `factor` in there too to get the other values.